# Parse Freebase RDF dump with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, freebase, elastic-map-reduce

I downloaded the rdf data dump from Freebase and what I need to extract is the name of every entity in English in Freebase.

Do I have to use Hadoop and MapReduce to do this, if so how? Or is there another way to extract the entity names?

It would be nice if each entity title / name were on its own line in a .txt file

Answer (score 2):

You could use Hadoop, but for such simple processing, you'd spend more time uncompressing and splitting the input than you would save in being able to do the search in parallel.  A simple `zgrep` would accomplish your task in much less time.

Something along the lines of this:

```
zegrep $'name.*@en\t\\.$' freebase-public/rdf/freebase-rdf-2013-09-15-00-00.gz | cut -f 1,3 | gzip > freebase-names-20130915.txt.gz
```

will give you a compressed two column file of Freebase MIDs and their English names.  You'll probably want to make the grep a little more specific to avoid false positives (and test it, which I haven't done).  This file is over 20GB compressed, so it'll take a while, but less time than even getting started to prepare a Hadoop job.

If you want to do additional filtering such as only extract entities with type of /common/topic, you may find that you need to move to a scripting language like Python to be able to look at and evaluate across multiple lines at once.

Comment: When I run `grep $'name.*@en\t\\.$' freebase-rdf | cut -f 1,3 | gzip > freebase-names-20130915.txt.gz` all I get is an empty file freebase-name-20130915.txt.gz and when I decompress that I get a .cpgz file and inside that is the .txt.gz file and it goes on forever.

Comment: What does it mean to be a type of /common/topic? I thought types were the categories the entities were sorted in like /people/person ?

Answer (score 1):

No I dont think you need to use Hadoop and MapReduce to do this. You can easily create a web service to extract RDF and send to a file. Following [1] blog post explains how you can extract RDF data using WSo2 Data services server. Similarly you can use WSO2 DSS data federation [2] feature to extract RDF data and send it to a excel data sheet

[1] - http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/09/extracting-rdf-data-using-wso2-data.html

[2] - http://prabathabey.blogspot.com/2011/08/data-federation-with-wso2-data-service.html

Comment: The data is 20GB+ compressed and something like 250GB uncompressed.  Creating a multi hundred GB database to run a single simple query doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se9vV8eIZME) for Google Compute Engine that shows you how to do this as well.

Comment: I haven't watched all of it yet, I've been meaning to. Doesn't that get only the most popular topics in Freebase? How do I get all the topics?

Comment: Also, the reason I am avoiding a Map / Reduce is because I recently read an article stating that "the data you have probably isn't big enough for Map / Reduce and there should be an easier way to deal with it. "

Comment: The RDF data dump contains all 40M+ topics in Freebase. I saw that article on HN as well. Tom's answer gives a good solution if you don't want to go the Hadoop route.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for explaining. I've been playing with Tom's grep command and variations of it, but all I'm getting is empty compressed dirs. Here is the grep command I tried: `grep $'name.*@en\t\\.$' freebase-rdf | cut -f 1,3 | gzip > freebase-names-20130915.txt.gz` Any idea why that is creating an empty .txt.gz that contains an empty .cpgz ? They ( the empty dirs ) infinitely contain each other.